# iOS - how to arrange multiple components vertically using AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have design the screen like below image

[image]

I solved this method..
set Y position of RedView,
set vertical spacing of GreenView,
set vertical spacing of BlueView...
But this method seems inefficient.

**Need help to achieve following Task.**

1. Components should always be stacked based on the center regardless of number. (because the number of components can change by requirements of client.)
2. Components have various height.

Is there a good way?

Comment: Add at what component what constraints you give?

Comment: if i understand qus correctly Then u can use tableView with custom cells for each component.Set component as center of tableView cell(change cell identifier).Based on your data pick a right cell to load components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Stack View Buddy .. It will make your life a lot easier ..

> That will give you an idea how to use them

https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

> Also go through the API Reference .. It will be helpful

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview

They will automatically adjust themselves on item size changed or screen orientation changed ..

Comment: While the link may helpful but avoid links only answers as the link may be removed or become invalid so better give a answer that can still help even if link is not available

Comment: Well, one of them is of Apple API Reference and other is from Raywanderlich .. None of them are going anywhere unless Stack View becomes Obsolete .. I can bet on that ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to drag your components from the object library and put them vertically into your view. Then select all the components and stack them vertically, using command: Editor -> Embed in -> Stack View or by clicking the stack view icon at the bottom of the screen next to the alignment icon.

Then centre the stack view vertically and horizontally in the view.

Stack views have a number of options that allow you to distribute your components within a stack view: use alignment and distribution options in the attributes inspector to achieve proper positioning.

For more advanced tips, read about autolayout and stack views on raywenderlich as suggested by Umer Farooq above.